# Deriving Newton-Gregory via Newton series

Tags: numerical-methods, interpolation

I am attempting a derivation of the Newton-Gregory polynomial interpolation by the means of [Newton Series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_difference#Newton%27s_series) and the calculus of finite differences. The formula usually given as defining $s = \frac{x-x_0}{h}$ and saying $ \displaystyle p(x) = p(x_0 + hs) = \sum_{n=0}^{k} {s\choose{n}}\Delta ^n [f](x_0)$ for $k$ data points $\{x_i: x_i = x_0 + ih\}$ being interpolated by a polynomial of degree at most $k$.

My thought process was as such. We are trying to fit the data of $f$ so take its Newton expansion around $x_0$. So \begin{equation}f(x) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{\Delta ^n f(x_0)}{n!}(x-x_0)^{\underline{n}} \end{equation}

And this is equal to
\begin{equation}f(x) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{\Delta ^n f(x_0)}{n!}(sh)^{\underline{n}} \end{equation}

And using the identity that $\frac{x^{\underline{k}}}{k!} = {x\choose k}$ , truncating to the degree of the polynomial and discarding any remainders \begin{equation*} \displaystyle p(x) = p(x_0 + hs) = \sum_{n=0}^{k} {sh\choose{n}}\Delta ^n [f](x_0) \end{equation*}

Which is... not the same, although very close and seems intuitive. What am I doing wrong. I am aware I have ignored convergence but let's assume $f$ has very strong properties to ensure this, I do not necessarily need a rigorous proof.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The *canonical* Newton interpolation formula of the function $f(x)$, 
over the $n+1$ points $x=0,1,\cdots,n$ is the $n$-degree polynomial
$$
p_{\,n} (x) = \sum\limits_{j = 0}^n {\left. {\Delta _{\,x} ^{\,j} f(x)} \right|_{x\, = \,0} {{x^{\,\underline {\,j\,} } } \over {j!}}} 
$$
where
$$
\left\{ \matrix{
  \Delta _{\,x} ^{\,0} f(x) = f(x) \hfill \cr 
  \Delta _{\,x} ^\, f(x) = f(x + 1) - f(x) \hfill \cr 
  \Delta _{\,x} ^{\,2} f(x) = \Delta _{\,x} ^\, \left( {\Delta _{\,x} ^\, f(x)} \right) = f(x + 2) - 2f(x + 1) + f(x) \hfill \cr 
  \quad \quad  \vdots  \hfill \cr 
  \Delta _{\,x} ^{\,q} f(x) = \sum\limits_{k = 0}^q {\left( { - 1} \right)^{\,q - k} \left( \matrix{
  q \cr 
  k \cr}  \right)f(x + k)}  \hfill \cr}  \right.
$$

That's because the polynomial for $x=0,\cdots,n$ takes all
the wanted values
$$
\eqalign{
  & p_{\,n} (m)\quad \left| {\;0 \le m \le n} \right. = \sum\limits_{j = 0}^n {\left. {\Delta _{\,x} ^{\,j} f(x)} \right|_{x\, = \,0} {{m^{\,\underline {\,j\,} } } \over j}}  =  \quad \quad (1)\cr 
  &  = \sum\limits_{j = 0}^n {\sum\limits_{k = 0}^j {\left( { - 1} \right)^{\,j - k} \left( \matrix{
  j \cr 
  k \cr}  \right)f(k){{m^{\,\underline {\,j\,} } } \over {j!}}} }  = \sum\limits_{j = 0}^{m \le n} {\sum\limits_{k = 0}^j {\left( { - 1} \right)^{\,j - k} \left( \matrix{
  m \cr 
  j \cr}  \right)\left( \matrix{
  j \cr 
  k \cr}  \right)f(k)} }  =  \quad \quad (2) \cr 
  &  = \sum\limits_{j = 0}^{m \le n} {\sum\limits_{k = 0}^m {\left( { - 1} \right)^{\,j - k} \left( \matrix{
  m \cr 
  j \cr}  \right)\left( \matrix{
  j \cr 
  k \cr}  \right)f(k)} }  =   \quad \quad (3)\cr 
  &  = \sum\limits_{j = 0}^m {\sum\limits_{k = 0}^m {\left( { - 1} \right)^{\,j - k} \left( \matrix{
  m \cr 
  k \cr}  \right)\left( \matrix{
  m - k \cr 
  j - k \cr}  \right)f(k)} }  = \sum\limits_{k = 0}^m {\left( \matrix{
  m \cr 
  k \cr}  \right)f(k)\sum\limits_{l = 0}^m {\left( { - 1} \right)^{\,l} \left( \matrix{
  m - k \cr 
  l \cr}  \right)} }  =  \quad \quad (4) \cr 
  &  = \sum\limits_{k = 0}^m {\left( \matrix{
  m \cr 
  k \cr}  \right)f(k)\left( {1 - 1} \right)^{\,m - k} }  = f(m) \quad \quad (5)\cr} 
$$

*(see note)*
and, as that, it gives the same result as any other polynomial interpolating approach.

Now, if the abscissas are not at $x=0,1,\cdots,n$ but at $x=x_0, x_0+h,\cdots,x_0+nh$
then you make a translation and a change of scale by putting
$$
\eqalign{
  & y = {{x - x_{\,0} } \over h}\quad  \Leftrightarrow \quad x = x_{\,0}  + h\,y  \cr 
  & f(x) = f(x_{\,0}  + h\,y) = g(y) \cr} 
$$
thereby getting
$$
\eqalign{
  & q_{\,n} (y) = \sum\limits_{j = 0}^n {\left. {\Delta _{\,y} ^{\,j} g(y)} \right|_{y\, = \,0} {{y^{\,\underline {\,j\,} } } \over {j!}}}  =   \cr 
  &  = \sum\limits_{j = 0}^n {\left. {\Delta _{\,y} ^{\,j} f(x_{\,0}  + h\,y)} \right|_{y\, = \,0} {1 \over {j!}}\left( {{{x - x_{\,0} } \over h}} \right)^{\,\underline {\,j\,} } }  \cr} 
$$

You can express the falling factorial as
$$
\eqalign{
  & \left( {{{x - x_{\,0} } \over h}} \right)^{\,\underline {\,j\,} }  = \left( {{{x - x_{\,0} } \over h}} \right)\left( {{{x - x_{\,0} } \over h} - 1} \right) \cdots \left( {{{x - x_{\,0} } \over h} - j + 1} \right) =   \cr 
  &  = {1 \over {h^{\,j} }}\left( {x - x_{\,0} } \right)\left( {x - \left( {x_{\,0}  + h} \right)} \right) \cdots \left( {x - \left( {x_{\,0}  + \left( {j - 1} \right)h} \right)} \right) \cr} 
$$
and thus expand the previous identity within the formalism 
of the *divided finite differences*, however the substance and the connection between the two ways should now be clear, and it is clear that somewhere you shall account for the scaling factor $1/h^j$.

----- notes to the equations for $p_n(m)$ ----

*line (2)*
 since $j$ is non-negative, the bound $k \le j$ is implicit in the 2nd Binomial C., and we can extend the sum for $k$ to $m$ (or even omit both bounds).

*line (3)*

the identity 
$$
\eqalign{
  & \left( \matrix{
  m \cr 
  j \cr}  \right)\left( \matrix{
  j \cr 
  k \cr}  \right) = {{m^{\,\underline {\,j\,} } } \over {j!}}{{j!} \over {\left( {j - k} \right)!k!}} = {{m^{\,\underline {\,k + \left( {j - k} \right)\,} } } \over {j!}}{{j!} \over {\left( {j - k} \right)!k!}} =   \cr 
  &  = {{m^{\,\underline {\,k\,} } \left( {m - k} \right)^{\,\underline {\,\left( {j - k} \right)\,} } } \over {\left( {j - k} \right)!k!}} = {{m^{\,\underline {\,k\,} } } \over {k!}}{{\left( {m - k} \right)^{\,\underline {\,\left( {j - k} \right)\,} } } \over {\left( {j - k} \right)!}} = \left( \matrix{
  m \cr 
  k \cr}  \right)\left( \matrix{
  m - k \cr 
  j - k \cr}  \right)\quad \left| \matrix{
  \;m \in \mathbb R \hfill \cr 
  \;j,k \in \mathbb Z \hfill \cr}  \right. \cr} 
$$

is one of the fundamental identities obeyed  by Binomial Coefficients, by some authors called *"Trinomial Revision"*

Comment: So the algebra doesn't work because the approach is incorrect? Lots of stuff I read claim Newton-Gregory interpolation is "just the Newton series" and I am trying to understand what they mean by it.

Comment: If $f(x)$ is a polynomial of degree $n$, thus defined by $n+1$ points, then Taylor and Newton series (which gets "automatically" truncated after the $n$-th term) obviously coincide. But if you truncate them at $m<n$, they will not in general coincide: you can easily construct by yourself some simple examples.

Comment: rereading your comment, it seems that I did not interpretate correctly your question: what is exactly your doubt ? what do you mean by *Gregory-Newton* interpolation ?

Comment: Using finite differences to interpolate polynomials arising as a special case of Newton's divided differences formulae. An example here https://nptel.ac.in/courses/122104019/numerical-analysis/Rathish-kumar/rathish-oct31/fratnode8.html

Wolfram provides another definition but I am not as familiar with the form they use, but it is probably equivalent. http://mathworld.wolfram.com/NewtonsForwardDifferenceFormula.html

Comment: Well, I think that (possibly) I got your point now, and recasted my answer.

Comment: Perfect, I realised just now that in the resources I used the step size was being taken into account but the notation was always just $\Delta$ and I came to update my question when I saw your excellent and comprehensive answer. Thanks.

Comment: @TheoDiamantakis: good, glad that I succeeded in catching the point and be of help. And that's good that you caught the point that the $\Delta$ symbol alone can, many times, be misleading and shall  be defined when used out of the normal convention for unit step. It is also good to put an index to underline the variable on which it works.

Comment: I've been looking over your proof that the canonical Newton series interpolates $f$, but I don't quite follow line 3, specifically how you obtained ${m-k \choose {n-k}}$ or why you can use the binomial theorem when the last term of the inner sum isn't $m-k$. Could you help me understand?

Comment: @TheoDiamantakis: I added some explanations, hope they are understandable.